# Php find all links with a given pattern in a string

Tags: php, regex

I am importing articles from a remote API endpoint, and on import I need to find all links in a string by a word. So, for example if I get a string that looks like this:

```
<a href='http://myhost.com/Se-hva-vi-gjoer'>Les mer </a>blbl blblb blblb blblb<a href='https://myhost.com/Se-hva-vi-gjoer/Positive-women'>Les mer </a>
```

I would have to find all links that have `myhost.com` in the string. I have tried with the this kind of preg_match:

```
preg_match_all('@(https?://myhost.com)?([^/]+)@i', $string , $linkMatches);
```

But, that gives me this kind of array:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:8 [
    0 => "<a href='http:"
    1 => "myhost.com"
    2 => "Se-hva-vi-gjoer'>Les mer <"
    3 => "a>blbl blblb blblb blblb<a href='https:"
    4 => "myhost.com"
    5 => "Se-hva-vi-gjoer"
    6 => "Positive-women'>Les mer <"
    7 => "a>"
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    0 => ""
    1 => ""
    2 => ""
    3 => ""
    4 => ""
    5 => ""
    6 => ""
    7 => ""
  ]
  2 => array:8 [
    0 => "<a href='http:"
    1 => "myhost.com"
    2 => "Se-hva-vi-gjoer'>Les mer <"
    3 => "a>blbl blblb blblb blblb<a href='https:"
    4 => "myhost.com"
    5 => "Se-hva-vi-gjoer"
    6 => "Positive-women'>Les mer <"
    7 => "a>"
  ]
]
```

And what I want is an array with this strings:

`http://myhost.com/Se-hva-vi-gjoer` and `https://myhost.com/Se-hva-vi-gjoer/Positive-women`

What would be the correct regex for that?

Comment: And what is the expected output? `http://myhost.com/Se-hva-vi-gjoer` and `https://myhost.com/Se-hva-vi-gjoer/Positive-women`? If you plan to collect all the `href` attribute values, you should consider using DOM methods in the first place.

Comment: yes, that is the expected output, I can't use DOM methods, since I am importing all that from an api, and then I need to parse the body text in my controller.

Comment: There should be no issue if you have the DOM parsing library installed. Look at [this example](https://3v4l.org/toTBa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
preg_match_all('/[\'\"](https?\:\/\/[^\'\"]?myhost.com[^\'\"]*)[\'\"]/i', $string , $linkMatches);
```